# cmd is not recognised in windows command prompt

Tags: windows-10

```
*C:\devel>cmd
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

*C:\devel>
```

Can any one help me to fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again ?

Comment: This is weird. I know it works in win7, however it mightn't work in win10. Would have to test.

Comment: works on windows 10 (just tested) but it depends on some settings for application aliases, in all cases you can use `START`

Comment: cmd works well in my PC

Answer (score 1):

Well, `cmd` is not a command for the Windows command prompt. You need to type `help` to get a list of command, or maybe search on google...

If you're looking for a way to start a new instance of the command prompt, use `START` it will work whatever the version or settings

Comment: Did it change with the introduction of Win8 or was it Win10? (in Win7 cmd.exe _is_ the name of the command interpreter)

Comment: You can always type `cmd.exe` to open a new instance of the command prompt, or `START`
But since you're already in the command prompt I don't really get why you would need that

Comment: @RomainIsnel Well, Windows normally looks for *thenameofexecutable*`.exe` so it should work to just type cmd (if it is in the %PATH% variable, and %PATHEXT% contains `.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

***`cmd` is not a command in "windows command prompt" or if you wont to start new Command prompt then you have to type***

```
C:\devel>start
```

> `start` is to open new command prompt window.